# Why most API paginations do not rely on HTTP Range header?

Tags: api, http, rest, pagination, hateoas

I've searched a lot but I can't find a good answer to this question.
Being a HATEOAS aficionado, I would think that this header fit perfectly:

```
    Range: item=1-20/100
```

In the HTTP spec, I don't understand some "contradictions":
The range unit can accept "other-range-unit"...

```
  range-unit       = bytes-unit | other-range-unit
  bytes-unit       = "bytes"
  other-range-unit = token
```

... yet the spec is later explicit:

> The only range unit defined by HTTP/1.1 is "bytes". HTTP/1.1 implementations MAY ignore ranges specified using other units.

Finally the spec ends with this statement:

> HTTP/1.1 has been designed to allow implementations of applications that do not depend on knowledge of ranges.

- Is any other unit than byte allowed ?
- If HTTP/1.1 was designed to allow app to not depend on range, what are the real drawback about relying on it for an API ?

NB: I don't care about "browsability".

Comment: The question you’re asking in the title answers itself with the info from the spec: Because “bytes” are in most situations not a usable measurement unit for pagination. And since other range units may be ignored, as well as may a range in general, it is just not usable for any API that should be accessible with _any_ HTTP implementation that is conform with the specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the answers that I gently borrowed from this question thanks to [@ptidel](https://twitter.com/Ptidel): [Content-Range header - allowed units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480193/content-range-header-allowed-units).

First, custom units are proposed in this draft [HTTP/1.1, part 5: Range Requests and Partial Responses](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-18.html#range.units)

Second, there is a subtle difference, the first statement has been made for parsing purpose

```
    range-unit       = bytes-unit | other-range-unit
    bytes-unit       = "bytes"
    other-range-unit = token
```

While the second statement has been made for producing HTTP request.

Finally, the whole comment from [Ferenc Mihaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981240/ferenc-mihaly) summarizes perfectly the situation:

> I conform to the HTTP spec when I'm sending [a custom range unit] and they conform to HTTP when they ignore it
>
> WebDAV uses HTTP extensions correctly, IMO, but rarely works over the Internet for exactly this reason